# Storing very large integers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, storage, blob

I need to store a very large number (tens of millions) of 512-bit SHA-2 hashes in a MySQL table. To save space, I'd like to store them in binary form, rather than a string a hex digits. I'm using an ORM ([DBix::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class.pm)) so the specific details of the storage will be abstracted from the code, which can inflate them to any object or structure that I choose.

MySQL's `BIGINT` type is 64 bits. So I could theoretically split the hash up amongst eight `BIGINT` columns. That seems pretty ridiculous though. My other thought was just using a single `BLOB` column, but I have heard that they can be slow to access due to MySQL's treating them as variable-length fields.

If anyone could offer some widsom that will save me a couple hours of benchmarking various methods, I'd appreciate it.

*<sub>Note: Automatic -1 to anyone who says "just use postgres!" :)</sub>*

Comment: just use postgres :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you considered 'binary(64)' ? See [MySQL binary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) type.

Answer (score 8):

Use the type [BINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html)(64) ?