# Can I keep my score values at TEXT based MySQL place?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing very large integers in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211413/storing-very-large-integers-in-mysql)

Hello I am creating a browser game and scores can be higher than 11 characters. So I learned that `INT` can keep informations that are under 11 characters long.

Can I keep them in `TEXT` format, are there any potential issues and risk if I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211413/storing-very-large-integers-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but first try to use bigint. 
And yes there is risks, for example you'll have some bugs trying to fetch chars with score > any value, or exact some value

Answer (score 0):

**[SEE Here for MYSQL Numeric Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)**

I'll recommend `BIGINT` but be aware that the maximum value for `BIGINT` is `9223372036854775807`. Make sure you can handle the value from `OverFlow`ing

```
mysql> SELECT (9223372036854775807 + 1) as Result;
+-------------------------+
| Result                  |
+-------------------------+
|    -9223372036854775808 |
+-------------------------+
```

in order to enable the operation to succeed in this case, convert the value to unsigned;

```
mysql> SELECT (CAST(9223372036854775807 AS UNSIGNED) + 1) as Result;
+-------------------------------------------+
| Result                                    |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                       9223372036854775808 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```