# MySQL very long number data type

Tags: mysql, database, types, sqldatatypes, bigint

Which data type should I use to store a number(ID) like "10196385171799537224"(21 digits) in MySQL database?

Comment: try checking out this question! it helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211413/storing-very-large-integers-in-mysql

Answer (score 5):

You can store it as `numeric(21,0)`

**[See SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f04e1/1)**

Answer (score 4):

Per the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-types.html), you'd need a `NUMERIC(21,0)`.

However, that's a unfeasibly large ID. Adding entries at a rate of one per microsecond, it would take over 300,000 years to reach that number. You might want to reconsider your design.